# Handling optional elements in mule with xpath

Tags: xpath, mule, mule-el

So I'm trying to save my SOAP Response to a db using xpath expressions like

```
 ...#[xpath('//Person/Name/Firstname').text], #[xpath('//Person/Name/Lastname').text],
#xpath('//Relations/Relation/RelationId/Id').text], #xpath('//Relations/Relation/Relationtype').text])).....
```

But I wonder how to handle the "Relation" element. It is optional, and if it exists it can exist several times and the elements can have different names depending of type of Relation.
If it exists I always want to save all of it so I wonder what the best way is to handle this?

Regards

*EDIT*

If the element "Relations" exists, it can have one or several "Relation" element and subelements with different names. I'm not sure how to handle it, maybe its best to use a ChoiceRouter first to check if "Relations" exist. If it does I'll need to have a "foreach" and then do huge amount of checks to see which subelements are there so I could save them all to the database.

Comment: Would you mind updating the question to expand on what you mean by "saving all of it"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use **ternary expression** for if/else in a single MEL expression
for your reference .. check pls this :- http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Control+Flow

for example the following checks the **Relation** element and if exists, it extracts `//Relations/Relation/RelationId/Id` or put your else condition and return **node.text**... you can modify as per your requirement :-

```
#[node = xpath('//Relations/Relation') != null ? xpath('//Relations/Relation/RelationId/Id').text : your else condition;node.text;]
```

Comment: Well, at least until I notice d that the whole thing blows when it tries to check '//Relations' when it doesn't exist at all ;)